# Angular 17 SSR, HTTP request server side only

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, hydration

I've been trying out Angular 17's SSR feature. Coming from Next.js, I'm wondering if there's any way to run code only on the server side?

I have tried to use platform ID to figure out where the request is running, and everything seems to be working, but when the application is getting hydrated, it clears out the data that was fetched on the server side.

Can I prevent this behavior somehow?

Comment: What is your usecase behind that ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I want to statically render some part of the UI without sending the user the transfer state.

Healthcare domain use case: before opening the page, the XML document about the user, healthcare providers, insurance, etc., should be fetched. This document is large, and I hardly believe the user wants to wait for the serialized response in the browser. I want to render parts of the UI that require data from this XML document.

I can create some service in front of the API that provides the XML document to get essential data, but I am wondering if there is any other way?

Comment: Not related to this question: In Next.js, I can write code that never leaves the server. Is there a similar feature in Angular? For example, can I make an API request with "hard-coded" secrets and use the response to provide data to the client?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do fetching server side only, you'll have to transfer that data to the client side if you need to render it.

This is what the [`TransferState`](https://angular.io/api/core/TransferState) is for (a kind of map to be used as a store).

By using `isPlatformServer()` you could store the data server side and then restore it on the client side :

```js
class MyService {
  
  platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  transferState = inject(TransferState);
  myKey = makeStateKey<MyDataInterface>('my-data');
    
  someMethod() {
    if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
      transferState.set(myKey, { /* server fetched data */ }); 
    } else {
      transferState.get(myKey); // Do whatever you need
    }
  }
}
```